# mysqldump performance on machine with big amount of memory

Tags: sql, performance, innodb, mysql

I'm doing backup of innodb database with **mysqldump**. It takes 2 min to perform a backup.
Is there any way how to speed it up?

I have machine with 120GB of RAM and I expect that my DB should fit in memory.

Database size on hard drive is around 8 GB:

```
[user@host:E018 mysql]$ du -hs database 
8.3G    database
```

Biggest table has 12054861 records and data size 2991587328.

I have tried to play with innodb_buffer_pool_size but I don't see big performance increase.
If I run mysqldump for first time it takes 2 min 7 sec. If I try it second time it takes around 2 min that is to slow.

I have also tried to archive data to avoid a lot of disk writes:
`mysqldump database |pigz > database-dmp.sql.gz` that has no influence on performance.

Running mysqldump on different machine from mysql engine does not change anything.
Probably mysql does not cache data to the memory or it sends data to the mysqldump to slow.

Here is configuration that I use:

```
max_heap_table_size=10G;
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_strict_mode=1
innodb_write_io_threads=4 
innodb_read_io_threads=4 
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
```

What else can I try to improve mysqldump performance?

Comment: why do you want backup faster than 2 minutes?

Comment: I have short time window where I can do maintenance work like taking backup. I have another databases that I want to backup. Also I need to take backup several times a day.

Comment: it's better to make database backup non-impacting, so you can take backups whenever you want.

Comment: What is non-impacting database backup please?

Comment: xtrabackup. It can throttle number of IOPS it does. Or you can setup a slave and take backups from it.